# SonarQube 6.4 Wrapper Stopped in Windows

Tags: windows, sonarqube

I am using SonarQube 6.4 version. When I am trying to start sonar in command prompt it gave me following error.

sonarqube-6.4

```
C:\sonar\sonarqube-6.4\sonarqube-6.4\bin\windows-x86-64> startsonar.bat
wrapper | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper | Launching a JVM…
jvm 1 | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1 | Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1 |
jvm 1 | 2019.05.20 16:39:22 INFO app[o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\sonar\sonarqube-6.4\sonarqube-6.4\temp
jvm 1 | 2019.05.20 16:39:22 INFO app[o.s.a.p.JavaProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[es]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djna.nosys=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\sonar\sonarqube-6.4\sonarqube-6.4\temp -cp ./lib/common/;./lib/search/ org.sonar.search.SearchServer C:\sonar\sonarqube-6.4\sonarqube-6.4\temp\sq-process2322798181221119258properties
jvm 1 | 2019.05.20 16:39:27 INFO app[o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
jvm 1 | 2019.05.20 16:39:27 INFO app[o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
wrapper | <-- Wrapper Stopped.
```

Comment: The information why it has been stopped is in `web.log` file.